# Sufficient algorithm for swapping elements to meet a specific condition

Tags: algorithm

You are given two positive number N and K, find the smallest number of swapping any two number from N to make two new numbers A and B and the difference (A - B) equals to K, if there any more than one solution, use the solution with the biggest A.

For e.g.

We have N = 9834216 and K = 8826, we swap 16 to form the new number 9168342, A = 9168 and B = 342, and A - B = 9168 - 342 = 8826.

Comment: What did you try? Show us the code!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let N = 9834216, K = 8826;
let count = 0;

function fn(nArr, k, n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    let temp = -k;
    if (temp <= 0) {
      return;
    }
    let tArr = [...nArr];
    while (temp > 0) {
      let temp1 = temp % 10;
      let tId = tArr.indexOf(temp1);
      if (tId < 0) {
        return;
      }
      tArr.splice(tId, 1);
      temp = Math.floor(temp / 10);
    }
    if (tArr.length == 0) {
      console.log((K - k) + "-" + (-k) + "=" + K);
      count++;
    }
  } else {
    for (let i in nArr) {
      let tArr = [...nArr];
      tArr.splice(i, 1);
      fn(tArr, k - Math.pow(10, n - 1) * nArr[i], n - 1);
    }
  }
}

function getAB(N, K) {
  let nArr = [],
    n = N;
  while (n > 0) {
    nArr.push(n % 10);
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  }
  nArr.sort();
  nArr.reverse();
  for (let i = nArr.length; i > nArr.length / 2; i--) {
    fn(nArr, K, i);
  }
}

getAB(N, K);
console.log(count + " solutions");
```

Comment: I think you got it in the wrong way, the question is about print the smallest number of swapping and the N after swapping, for e.g. "1 9168342"